# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.android.launcher3.util.FlagOp, but class was expected

Tags: java, android, apktool

I'm trying to mod an launcher application and I'm currently stuck at this error `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.android.launcher3.util.FlagOp, but class was expected` which I quite don't understand since by doing a google search for the error it seems that this happens when when your runtime classpath is different than your compile time classpath. But it doesn't make sense since I'm rebuilding the app with the same code but few modifications using apktool, and I'm not really touching the specified implementation. What could be the issue?

```
at com.android.launcher3.util.FlagOp.c(Unknown Source:0)    
at com.android.launcher3.util.i.apply(Unknown Source:4)     
at com.android.launcher3.icons.BitmapInfo.withFlags(Unknown Source:11)  
at com.android.launcher3.icons.cache.BaseIconCache.getDefaultIcon(Unknown Source:37)    
at com.android.launcher3.icons.cache.BaseIconCache.isDefaultIcon(Unknown Source:0)  
at com.android.launcher3.icons.IconCache.loadIconSubsection(Unknown Source:233)     
at com.android.launcher3.icons.IconCache.lambda$getTitlesAndIconsInBulk$14(Unknown Source:33)   
at com.android.launcher3.icons.IconCache.h(Unknown Source:0)    
at h.o.accept(Unknown Source:6)     
at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1292)     
at com.android.launcher3.icons.IconCache.getTitlesAndIconsInBulk(Unknown Source:36)     
at com.android.launcher3.model.LoaderTask.loadWorkspace(Unknown Source:2966)    
at com.android.launcher3.model.LoaderTask.loadWorkspace(Unknown Source:7)   
at com.android.launcher3.model.LoaderTask.run(Unknown Source:123)   
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)  
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: What apktool version do you use? What happens if you just decompile and recompile the app without making any changes?